# GAMs with multiple time series predictors

Tags: multivariate-analysis, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a binomial classification (yes/no) made on about 100 words. For each word, I can compute several time series (fo, intensity, etc.). I’m finding difficult to model (using GAMs) the outcome, using as predictors the time series. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you mean for a single word you have a single value (yes/no, 0/1) but you also have one or more time series of observations associated with that word, then you might look into the linear functional models where a summation convention allows one to use sums or weighted means of the time series values as the predictor in the model of the yes/no values over the data set of multiple words. For example: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/linear.functional.terms.html

Comment: Thanks Gavin! I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson, I've been trying to apply the examples included in the link you sent me but I'm having difficulties to include a matrix per file in a dataframe. I put each matrix as a list, in a workable dataframe here: [Data for GAM](https://onkyo.u-aizu.ac.jp/Data4GAM.Rdata) and I was wondering if you wouldn't mind to give it a try.  The dataframe has four columns (1: word, 2: proportion of times the word was rated as 'Yes', 3: the number of subjects that rated the word, 4: a matrix with the measured features---time series). Your help is much appreciated!